# how to run C function in iphone SDk?

Tags: iphone

i have added one .h and .c file ,but i want to call the function which is in .c file from
viewController?any help?if i add .h file and call that function linker error comes?

Comment: You should post the code you are trying to run, and compilers errors you are getting.

Comment: if u say, syntax, how can we call, it will help to me

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the ".c" file to your Xcode project, and you need to make sure that it is checked off in Xcode. If you make sure it is checked, then the source file should be linked into your project correctly.